# Symbols not found for architecture when building Cocoa Framework used in Static Library subproject

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I built a pretty simple Cocoa Framework in Xcode for use on an iOS device (not simulator). I dropped this framework into another project that builds a static library. When I build this static library it succeeds without error. No problems yet.

NOW:
I have an actual iOS app project that includes the static library project as a subproject.
[image: project layout]

When I try building this app I get 'no symbols found for architecture' errors regarding the two classes I am trying to use that are defined in my cocoa framework:
[image: build errors]

I'm not only building the framework for the active architecture:
[image: framework settings]

I've verified that it is indeed built for both armv7 and arm64 in Terminal:

```
Kevins-MBP-2:ASI.framework kevin$ lipo -info ASI
Architectures in the fat file: ASI are: armv7 arm64
```

The **only way** to get this building successfully is if I **also** drop my cocoa framework into the iOS app project, **in addition** to it already existing in my static library project. I feel like I shouldn't have to have the framework in both projects. Only the static library actually uses the framework. The iOS app project does not need to know about the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Static libraries don't contain dependent libraries, so whenever you link against a static library you need to supply the dependent libraries they use to the linker.

Basically you do need to also link the executable against this Cocoa Framework as you have stated in the last sentence of your question.

Comment: Hmm okay. What if I were to change the static library project to build a cocoa framework instead of a static library? Would the same apply?

Comment: No, however you would still need to package the dependent framework with the app, so it's almost as much hassle.

Comment: So if it still needs to be packaged with the app, what is different? You're saying it still needs to be packaged in both the new framework (former static library) as well as the iOS app target? So it still exists in two places?

Comment: "what is different?"  Not much.  If you have exe -> static lib -> framework then you have to copy one framework into the app bundle.  If you have exe -> framework -> framework then you need to copy 2 frameworks into the app bundle.